# Blend file takes a long time to load and has long pre-render time (Synchronizing object)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I've set GPU render devices setting in both places:

[image]

[image]

I've set tiles from 256 to 2048 and to 8192.

I have RTX 3060TI and it takes 6 minutes to render 1 frame, which means 20 hours to finish my 200 frames. I think this is too slow and my GPU was only occupied for 20%.

I have set lights in the scene, what else can I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've uploaded my Blender files in case anyone need:

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jAXKj_ETtRHBMGYa76Wjh7hmjlQ2V4VK/view?usp=sharing

Video footage: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yi5QACM6ctNFA9eTZRcTQ_YPYuP_tOTR/view?usp=sharing

---

**Note: this question is not a duplicate. The problem is related to topology and modifiers which results in lag and long calculation times. Can we reopen it?**

Comment: The first file is a .blend1 backup file so there's no point putting a link to that here and your Blend file causes Blender (both 3.6.5 and 3.3.10) to hang while loading here.

Comment: I just don't know that the problem was caused by GPU not fully loaded or caused by various render settings. Because I found my computer only loaded 20% when it was doing rendering, I need help determining if the insufficient GPU usage is the bottleneck.

Comment: What Blender version do you use? I can't open your blend file with Blender 4.0 beta. It just hangs. Appending the collection doesn't work either. It seems one of the objects freezes Blender. It sounds a bit strange that a 3060 TI takes 6 min for max. 64 samples because the scene doesn't look that complex. The tile size only matters when you render out a huge image or when you are low on VRAM. If the rendered image is larger than the tile size (2048x2048 by default) it's rendered in parts to save memory.

Comment: My blender version is 3.6.5, my computer memory is 64G, and thats why I feel like strange for only 20% GPU running, the scene is really simple...

Comment: I have the same Blender version and just 32 GB. I don't think it's the memory because the memory usage is low. It's the CPU that goes crazy when I try to open the file or try to append this  "平面.002" object (the first character looks different, I can't copy it). What is this? It seems this is the troublemaker. Everything else I can append to a new file. The model looks like a black loudspeaker, black world, simple materials. It renders quickly, less than 30 seconds on CPU(!) with max. 64 samples. There is also footage (movie clip) with some tracking data. Where is that used?

Comment: You should mention that it takes almost 3 minutes(!) to open the file so we don't think Blender just died. Actually, you have 2 problems: long loading time & long render time. The problem is at the back plate that is behind the the grille of the loudspeaker. It looks like this object was created by a curve or SVG file. You use a *Solidify*, a *Bevel*, and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. The problem is the bad topology + the modifiers, especially the Subd - it takes several minutes(!) to calculate it. Since viewport has 1 level and render has 2 levels it takes even longer for render (6 min!)

Comment: Fix: Remove the *Subdivision Surface* modifier (the last one at the bottom), remove the *Bevel* modifier (the 2nd one) or at least reduce the levels to 3 (it's a back plate, nobody sees it ;-). Additionally, you can reduce the number of vertices from 310 to 31 with the menu entry *Mesh > Clean > Limited Dissolve*. The mesh still has a big ngon (face with more than 4 vertices) which is not ideal but it no longer take several minutes to calculate and render.

Comment: Thank u so much! I finally understand what happend, I created this plain to avoid light reflections from the inside. And.. the moive tracking data is used for tracking the camera movement? Am I right? 

I apologize for I didn't mentioned that it takes 3 minutes to open my blender file, because this is my first blender file, so that I thought every blender file has the same open speed, it is my fault. Anyway, you helped me alot, thanks!